# How to resolve ErrorException: Undefined index: database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, firebase-realtime-database, database-connection, laravel-8

i am using laravel and firebase database i want to make my default database connection as a `firebase` for that i added some details in the `config/database.php` file when i hit any api it's throwing an following error can you please help me to resolve this issue

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

  
    'default' => 'firebase',

  
    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
        'firebase' => array(
            'driver'  =>  'firebase',
            'host'      => 'https://mydomain-34082-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/',
            'token'     => 'F1tet4K4DjzwAsU9lWTpjyNvYC5kGq49KcxtRAxd',
            'timeout'   => 10,
            'sync'      => false,           // OPTIONAL: auto-sync all Eloquent models with Firebase?
        )

    ],
];
```

**Error**

```
ErrorException: Undefined index: database in file myproj-v8/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php on line 76
```

Comment: you are missing the `database` key in your `firebase` conf

Comment: @ml59, i added after that it's throwing an error  InvalidArgumentException: Unsupported driver [firebase].

Comment: Out of the box, Laravel doesn't support Firebase as a database driver. You can try to find a package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @ml59, Laravel doesn't support firebase as a default driver due to it not being an SQL. as per laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database), it only supports the following 4 databases with the latest laravel 9 version.

1. MariaDB 10.2+
2. MySQL 5.7+
3. PostgreSQL 10.0+
4. SQLite 3.8.8+
5. SQL Server 2017+

Your best option would be to use a library such as https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync, where you can connect Firebase with your application and use SyncsWithFirebase trait to sync with your model.

Comment: i used this package but the relational tables data is not reflecting into the firebase

Comment: if possible can you send me any example how to use for relational tables

Comment: @usersuser here is a good example https://pociot.dev/16-using-eloquent-models-with-the-firebase-realtime-database, although the author has used Vue.js for the frontend you can use it still by adjusting the behavior of the controller's response for your blade view of API.